# release android map API keys from Google non-functional

Tags: android

The release keys that the Map API service issues to me do not work. The debug key works fine, even with debuggable set to false.

I think this problem is with Google, I think I am doing everything correctly.

Has anyone else ever encountered such a problem? How about other explanations or fix ideas?

Comment: How did you test the release key? Have you tested it with a signed apk on a device?

Answer (score 0):

As I not fully understand your process:

If you uses your release key to generate the map key, than you need to export a signed build with eclipse. This build can be used on a device for installing and testing if the map appears. The same build can than be published on the market.

If you combine the release key generation for the map and the release build procedure you should have an apk that can be installed anywhere and it should work and show the map.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got that fixed after a lot of stress . I just kept reapplying for the keys and following the steps carefully and finally it worked. I still do not know what I did wrong.

- Ian in Halifax